# Refresh cart once cart item is removed with ajax in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I use an AJAX call to delete/remove the items from the cart. Right now it works fine but I hae to reload/refresh the page to update the cart and I was thinking if there might be a much smoother way to do this.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'delete_item_from_cart');

function delete_item_from_cart(){ ?>
   <script>

    var ajaxdelete = {
            ajax_url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
    };
    $('.remove-item-custom').on('click', e => {

            let currentItem = e.currentTarget;
            var product_id = $(currentItem).attr("data-product_id");
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxdelete.ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 
                  action: "product_remove", 
                  product_id: product_id
                },success: function(data){
                    console.log('data);
                    window.location.reload(); // IS THERE A BETTER WAY??
                }
              });
            e.preventDefault();
       });
   </script>
<?php }



add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_remove', 'product_remove' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'product_remove' );


function product_remove() {
  global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
  session_start();
  $cart = $woocommerce->cart;

  foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item){
      if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] ){
        $cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
  }
}
return $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
exit();
}
```

So, any help is appreciated! There must be another way...

**EDIT**

in my cart.php I have this:

```
<div class="product-remove">
<?php
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" class="remove remove-item-custom" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
            esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
            esc_attr( $product_id ),
            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
        ), $cart_item_key );
    ?>                  
</div>
```

Comment: by default WooCommerce Remove item by ajax without reloading the pages, so can please mentioned where is this custom button that you add it?

Comment: Actually this is the default button. I just added a custom class @kashalo Please see my updated question

Comment: Please remember that: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.